# Using a SerialBlob vs byte[]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using hibernate to store and retrieve data from a MySQL database. I was using a byte array but came across the SerialBlob class. I can use the class successfully but I cant seem to find any difference between using the SerialBlob and a byte array. Does anyone know the basic differences or possible situations you wish to use a SerialBlob inlue of a byte[] are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that the `SerialBlob` is just a thin abstraction around a `byte[]`, but:

- Are you working in a team?
- Do you sometimes make mistakes?
- Are you lazy with writing comments?
- Do you sometimes forget what your code from a year ago actually does?

If you anwsered any of the above questions with a *yes*, you should probably use [`SerialBlob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialBlob.html).

It's basically the same with any other abstraction around a simple data structure (think `ByteBuffer`, for example) or another class. You want to use it over `byte[]`, because:

1. It's more descriptive. A `byte[]` could be some sort of cache, it could be a circular buffer, it could be some sort of integrity checking mechanism gone wrong. But if you use `SerialBlob`, it's obvious that this is just a blob of binary data from the database / to be stored in the database.

   Instead of manual array handling, you use methods on the class, which is, again, easier to read if you don't know the code. Even trivial array manipulation must be comprehended by the reader of your code. A method with a good name is self-descriptive.

   This is helpful for your teammates and also for you when you'll read this code in a year.
2. It's more error proof. Every time you write any new code, there's a good chance you had made a bug in it. It may be not visible at first, but it is probably in there. The `SerialBlob` code has been tested by thousands of people around the world and it's safe to say that you won't get any bugs associated to it.

   Even if you're sure you got your byte array handling right, because it's so straightforward, what if somebody else finds your code in half a year and starts "optimizing" things? What if he reuses an old blob, or messes up with your magic array padding? Every single off-by-one error in index manipulating will corrupt your data and that might not be detected right away (You *are* writing unit tests, aren't you?).
3. It restricts you to only a handful of possible interactions. This might actually look like a demerit, but it's not! It ensures you won't be using your blob as a local temporary variable after you're done with it. It ensures you won't try to make a `String` out of it or anything silly. It makes sure you'll only use it as a blob. Again, clarity and safety.
4. It's already written and always looks the same. You don't have to write a new implementation for every project, or read ten different implementations in ten different projects. If you'll ever see a `SerialBlob` in anyone's project, the usage will be clear to you. Everyone uses the same one.

---

**TL; DR:** A few years ago (or maybe still in C), using a `byte[]` would be ok. In Java (and OOP in general), try to use a specific class designed for the job instead of a primitive (low level) structure as it more clearly describes your intents, produces less errors and reduces the length of your code in the long run.