# OpenJPA: Exception when persisting a SerialBlob

Tags: java, jpa, serialization, blob, openjpa

My database table has a column which will contain serialized object data. The corresponding JPA entity has a field of type `javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob` (which implements `java.sql.Blob`).

I had to choose between `byte[]` and `SerialBlob`. After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16290257/395879) I decided to use `SerialBlob`.

The field is named "notificationData". I defined an additional convenience method `setNotification()` which takes a `Notification`-object, serializes it and then calls `setNotificationData()`.

Everything works fine using Hibernate. But when using OpenJPA (requirement on production server), an exception is thrown when trying to persist a new entity with notification data:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1673300 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Encountered unmanaged object "javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@c1d77a2a" in life cycle state  unmanaged while cascading persistence via field "com.mycompany.MyEntity.notificationData" during flush.  However, this field does not allow cascade persist. You cannot flush unmanaged objects or graphs that have persistent associations to unmanaged objects.
 Suggested actions: a) Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL (JPA annotations) or "persist" or "all" (JPA orm.xml), 
 b) enable cascade-persist globally, 
 c) manually persist the related field value prior to flushing. 
 d) if the reference belongs to another context, allow reference to it by setting StoreContext.setAllowReferenceToSiblingContext().
```

This is the related entity code:

```
@Lob @Basic
@Column(name = "NOTIFICATION_DATA", nullable = true)
public Blob getNotificationData() {
    return notificationData;
}

public void setNotificationData(Blob notificationData) {
    this.notificationData = notificationData;
}

@Transient
public Notification getNotification() throws SQLException, IOException {
    if (getNotificationData() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (notification == null) {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(getNotificationData().getBinaryStream());
        try {
            notification = (Notification) ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed de-serializing notification data", e);
        }
        ois.close();
    }
    return notification;
}

public void setNotification(Notification notification) throws SQLException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(notification);
    oos.close();
    synchronized (this) {
        this.notification = null;
        this.setNotificationData(new SerialBlob(baos.toByteArray()));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?